# How to: After js validation showing processing img

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, validation

Im trying to get a processing image showing after a successful submit with is validated by gen_validatorv4.js.

The problem is the formdata is going to a php file thats post data to google speadsheet. And that takes like 3-10 seconds so people click again on the submit button. Thats why I want a processing image. Any ideas how to do this?

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#ajax_loading').show();}

????

Or any help is welcome!

Comment: before posting via ajax (e.g click(function() { }) or submit(function(){ })), load a container and show loading image, after success: function(data) { /*remove that loading image*/ }

Answer (score 0):

bind a click event to the submit button and show the ajax_loading image in the click event.  the only way to hide it is when you receive the response event.  when you get the response back you can hide the ajax_loading image.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of jQuery for these issues, you can try [jQuery NimbleLoader](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/nimbleLoader) for the loading image, I would also suggest trying [how to enable/disable an element using jQuery](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2008/12/how-to-disableenable-element-with.html) to enable or disable to form to prevent double submission.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this site: http://www.ajaxload.info/ and generate yourself a image.

Lets say the image is called **loader.gif**

Then if your form is like that `<form id="myform">` 
your jquery will look like that:

```
$('#myform').submit(function(){
       $('#myform').prepend("<div id=\"loader\"></div>");
       ... do stuff here ...
        $('#loader').remove();
})
```

and you will have this CSS:

```
#loader {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background: url("loader.gif") no-repeat center center;
}
```